# Sum of consecutive prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider that $\mathcal{P}(x)$ represents the $x$-nth prime number.

Let let $y$ be a natural number and $p$ be the prime $\mathcal{P}(y).$ Then let $\mathcal{D}(p)$ the least $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ which

$ \sum\limits_{i = y+1}^{n} \mathcal{P}(i) $

is a prime number. For example:

$\mathcal{D}(2) = 10$, because $\sum\limits_{i = 2}^{10} \mathcal{P}(i) = 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17 + 19 + 23 + 29 = 127$.

For every even number $m > 2$ there exists a prime number $q$ such that $\mathcal{D}(q) = m$?

Comment: Nice little theory :)…… But just to clarify, would $\mathcal{D}(3)$ equal, $\sum_{i=3}^n \mathcal{P}(i)$ for some $n$ or $\sum_{i=2}^n\mathcal{P}(i)$, because $y$ can be natural. I am confused with the $P(y)$ part because you just said the same thing for $x$.

Comment: I think you need something like $n > y+1$ otherwise $n=y+1$ is the trivial solution for all inputs.  What $p$ input makes $D(p) = 8$?  I don't believe there are any.  There are only 6 possible y values, only one of which makes a prime with n=8, and that one isn't the smallest n.

Comment: Have you tested this for every $m$ up to 100 or 1000 or something, 674?

Comment: Earth to 674, come in please.

Comment: @user477343, in this case, $\mathcal{D}(3)$ use $\sum\limits_{i = 3}^{n} \mathcal{P}(i)$, because $3$ is the second prime number (thus $y = 2.$) I will add other example to clarify this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tested this for all prime numbers between $2$ and $41161739.$ In this case, all even numbers until $242$ appears at least once. The largest value I found for $\mathcal{D}$ was $350$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for that explanation. I got the value of $y$ and the primes mixed up. Sorry about that :)